# Prove for definition $\lim_{z\to-i}z^2+1=0$

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

help

Proof:  By definition

$$\lim_{z\to-i}z^2+1=0$$

if given $\epsilon >0$ I can find $\delta>0 $ such that,.

If $0<|z+i|<\delta$ then $|z^2+1|<\epsilon $

---

$$|z^2+1|=|z^2-i^2|=|(z-i)(z+i)|<\delta |z-i|$$

then??

Comment: I looked up to all of your questions, and I found out that you did not accept answers at all. As a matter of courtesy, you should learn how to up vote answers (when you reach enought reputation). But you can accept answer by clicking the check mark. I think, its time for you to read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/why-should-we-accept-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Start by assuming that $|z+i|<1$. Then by the triangle inequality we get

$$\begin{align}|z-i|&=|(z+i)+(-2i)|\\
&\leq |z+i|+|-2i|\\
&=|z+i|+2\\&<1+2\\&=3.
\end{align}$$

Choose $\delta=\min\{1,\epsilon/3\}$. Then, $\delta\leq 1$ and $\delta\leq \frac{\epsilon}{3}$. Thus, if $0<|z+i|<\delta$ then 
$$|z^2+1|=|z^2-i^2|=|(z-i)(z+i)|<\delta |z-i|<3\delta\leq \epsilon.$$
Done.

Comment: why i can assuming that $|z+i|<1$??

Comment: @mathnw We do that in order to get a bound for the factor $|z-i|$ as what I did in the answer.

Comment: im sorry,, but why $|-2i|<4$??

Comment: |−2i|=4 because definition of distance/abs in complex numbers

Comment: but,, |-2i|=2 or no?